# Not being able to post multipart in nodejs

Tags: node.js

My nodejs app is using cors:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Thanks to that, I can send requests from my client (from another ip address). POST and GET work.
They got a:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

However, when I upload a file, I get a cors error. The content type is then:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
```

In my app.js I have stuff like:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "200mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json'}));
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` also
you can reference this post: [CORS problem if "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971336/cors-problem-if-content-type-multipart-form-data)