# Passing a file from frontend to middleware goes into CORS issue

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes, cors

I am using `react-node` in my project. And I am uploading a file from my laptop, and the front-end is supposed to send it to the backend. While everything works smoothly on my local, when I deploy this on `kubernetes` I end up in the following errors:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://MY_BACKEND_LINK. (Reason: header ‘type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response)`

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://MY_BACKEND_LINK. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

`Error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource`

My nginx-ingress file looks like the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "$http_origin"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
spec:
  rules:
...
```

I have checked other resources such as [CORS problem if "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971336/cors-problem-if-content-type-multipart-form-data) or the official nginx kubernetes documentation https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/, and I acted accordingly: set the headers to "*" and increased the file size to `50m`. Though the error persisted. So I ended up to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4099) that explained they solved it with [this approach](https://imti.co/413-request-entity-too-large/). So my nginx config file changed to this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "$http_origin"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
spec:
  rules:
...
```

But once again, no luck. The same errors come up. Am I doing something wrong in my nginx file? How can I pass my file from the front-end to the back-end without encountering the CORS issue?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: We are hosting Kubernetes on Oracle with OKE: Oracle Kubernetes Engine

Comment: According to your second error, I found [this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed). Could you take some tests to check if any of that reasons appears in your case?

Answer (score 1):

At the very end it was something more trivial then I expected. The nginx file should start with `apiVersion: extensions/v1` and not with `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`.

Complete file:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
  name: gateway-ingress
spec:
...
```